# jq regex test() selecting unexpected values

Tags: json, regex, amazon-web-services, jq, amazon-ecr

I am trying to parse the JSON from `aws ecr describe-images`, and return a result with a specific image tag, matching a pattern, from the list. In particular I get an array with many of these entries:

```json
{
  "imageDetails": [
    {
      "registryId": "997652729005",
      "repositoryName": "events",
      "imageDigest": "sha256:5b649219a3abc5e903b27fd947f375df8634c883432a69e40d245ac2393d67b2",
      "imageTags": [
        "events-test-build-340"
      ],
      "imageSizeInBytes": 314454408,
      "imagePushedAt": "2021-01-12T10:42:51-05:00",
      "imageScanStatus": {
        "status": "COMPLETE",
        "description": "The scan was completed successfully."
      },
      "imageScanFindingsSummary": {
        "imageScanCompletedAt": "2021-01-12T10:43:00-05:00",
        "vulnerabilitySourceUpdatedAt": "2021-01-12T04:45:25-05:00",
        "findingSeverityCounts": {}
      },
      "imageManifestMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "artifactMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json"
    },
    {
      "registryId": "997652729005",
      "repositoryName": "events",
      "imageDigest": "sha256:0fae259bcfe02c8cf0ec3746aae668b3166960e7119467496df9aedfbc2c8c5b",
      "imageTags": [
        "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250-433",
        "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250",
        "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250-433-dev",
        "events-prod-build-433"
      ],
      "imageSizeInBytes": 316110570,
      "imagePushedAt": "2020-12-21T03:11:52-05:00",
      "imageScanStatus": {
        "status": "COMPLETE",
        "description": "The scan was completed successfully."
      },
      "imageScanFindingsSummary": {
        "imageScanCompletedAt": "2020-12-21T03:12:02-05:00",
        "vulnerabilitySourceUpdatedAt": "2020-11-03T20:21:09-05:00",
        "findingSeverityCounts": {}
      },
      "imageManifestMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "artifactMediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the output to be something like this:

```json
{
  "tag": [
    "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250"
  ],
  "sha": "sha256:5b649219a3abc5e903b27fd947f375df8634c883432a69e40d245ac2393d67b2",
  "imagePushedAt": "2021-01-12T10:42:51-05:00"
}
```

The challenge is to pick the images that have a tag whose name includes **`*prod-build*`** (a deployed production build), but then return a the tag having **no dashes** in it, which is the tag we actually use.  (Yes, this is entirely defective, I know).

I have gotten pretty far:

```bash
cat ecr-describe-images-events.json 
  | jq '.imageDetails[] 
  | {tag: .imageTags, sha: .imageDigest, date_pushed: .imagePushedAt} 
  | select( .tag | contains(["prod-build"])) 
  .tag[] |= walk(
    if type=="string" then 
      select(
        match("^[^-]+$")
      ) 
    else 
      null 
    end
  )'
```

So, from the `imageDetails` array, get and name elements, then from the array of tags select the nodes that have a tag with the string `prod-build`. From these nodes, find the
`tags` array element whose name does not include dashes, and return that.

The last part, which I have done with `select`, `walk`, and `match` is behaving differently than I expect.  I am getting:

```json
{
  "tag": [
    "events-test-build-340"
  ],
  "sha": "sha256:5b649219a3abc5e903b27fd947f375df8634c883432a69e40d245ac2393d67b2",
  "date_pushed": "2021-01-12T10:42:51-05:00"
}
{
  "tag": [
    "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250",
    "events-prod-build-433",
    null,
    null
  ],
  "sha": "sha256:8638389b7d83869b17b1c74ff30740d7cf8eff4574100c1270f20d4686252552",
  "date_pushed": "2021-02-17T13:11:42-05:00"
}
```

If I don't include the last part, starting `walk(...)` I get the correct nodes.  But when I do use `walk` with match or test, I get back array elements that don't match my regexp.

I am not fixed on my approach, or on the output format: I just need the three fields in some structure. What have I failed to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `del` to delete all tags that match a certain criterion:

```
.imageDetails[]
| {
    tag: .imageTags,
    sha: .imageDigest,
    date_pushed: .imagePushedAt
}
| select(.tag | contains(["prod-build"]))
| del(.tag[] | select(contains("-")))
```

First selects those objects with a "prod-build" tag and then deletes all other tags from the list.

Output:

```json
{
  "tag": [
    "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250"
  ],
  "sha": "sha256:0fae259bcfe02c8cf0ec3746aae668b3166960e7119467496df9aedfbc2c8c5b",
  "date_pushed": "2020-12-21T03:11:52-05:00"
}
```

Comment: All good answers; yours wins as the simplest and most readable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want s.t. like:

```
jq '.imageDetails[] 
  | {tag: .imageTags, sha: .imageDigest, date_pushed: .imagePushedAt} 
  | select( any(.tag[]; test("prod-build")?))
  | .tag |= map(select(test("^[^-]+$")? ))'
```

You will have to tweak this if you want to avoid selecting any objects for which .tag would otherwise be the empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variant using `contains` for both checks, with the second one negated using `not`:

```bash
jq '.imageDetails[] | select(.imageTags | any(contains("prod-build"))) | {
  tag: .imageTags | map(select(contains("-") | not)),
  sha: .imageDigest,
  date_pushed: .imagePushedAt
}'
```

```json
{
  "tag": [
    "6debaabc26cc82a4011ea9c71854cebac7a57250"
  ],
  "sha": "sha256:0fae259bcfe02c8cf0ec3746aae668b3166960e7119467496df9aedfbc2c8c5b",
  "date_pushed": "2020-12-21T03:11:52-05:00"
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/7by82OiuQL3)